# FireBase & Firebase Storage - is it possible to upload file to Storage and record the url into FireBase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I would like to find out if when I upload for example 3 files into storage, I can at the same time record in FireStore Database the name of the record in Storage. The objective would be then to be able to show in a page a picture saved in Storage, but only in a specific document.
I am not sure if it is clear enough. If it is not the case, I can give more color.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is totally possible. You should first upload the files, then, for each file, get a long lived download URL with the [`getDownloadURL`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#download-urls) method and save the URLs in a Firestore doc. You should give a try, by writing some code to implement this proposed approach, and if you encounter some problems with your code, ask a specific question. In other words, your question needs some more focus, see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Great. Many thanks. I will follow your recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed upload an image thanks to the `putFile` method and and retreive the uploaded document url thanks to the `getDownloadUrl` method.

Here is an sample code for an upload file function:

```
  Future<void> uploadFile(File file) async {
    try {
      Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref('avatars/avatar1.png');
      TaskSnapshot task = await ref.putFile(file);

      // Here you can keep your URL to later save it in a firestore document for example
      documentUrl = await task.ref.getDownloadURL();
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // Todo handle exceptions
    }
  }
```

Usually I like to add a boolean isLoading, to wrap my upload function between the true, false setState. That way I can easily manage an overlay or loading screen to disable any user input if it is necessary.